# categories<-subgaterories->plan how to get categories id wise fetch data laravel

Tags: laravel

**i want **

```
  $PlanDetails= PalnCategory::select('id','title')->with('Categorys'[subplandetails])->get();
```

**my api response**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "category 1",
        "categorys": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "subcategor_name": "regular"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "subcategor_name": "primum"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "category 2",
        "categorys": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "subcategor_name": "cat2 reg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**i want to show**

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"category 1",
      "categorys":[
         {
            "id":5,
            "subcategor_name":"regular",
            "plans":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"plan1"
               },
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"plan2"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":6,
            "subcategor_name":"primum",
            "plans":[
                {
                   "id":3,
                   "name":"plan3"
                },
                {
                   "id":4,
                   "name":"plan4"
                }
             ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"category 2",
      "categorys":[
         {
            "id":7,
            "subcategor_name":"cat2 reg",
            "plans":[
                {
                   "id":3,
                   "name":"plan3"
                },
                {
                   "id":4,
                   "name":"plan4"
                }
             ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**my model**

```
 public function Categorys()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PlanSucategory::class)->select('id','subcategor_name');
    }
public function PlanDetails()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PlanDetail::class);
    }
```

**my controller**

```
 $PlanDetail= PalnCategory::select('id','title')->with('Categorys','PlanDetails')->get();

       return response()->json($PlanDetail);
```

here subcategories id same anthor to table categories<-subcategories->plandetails  but i want to fetch data categories->subcategories->plandetails

here subcategories id same anthor to table categories<-subcategories->plandetails  but i want to fetch data categories->subcategories->plandetailshere subcategories id same anthor to table categories<-subcategories->plandetails  but i want to fetch data categories->subcategories->plandetails

Comment: Duplicated? [laravel pivot table joins api response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010238/laravel-pivot-table-joins-api-response)

Comment: yes but i explained detailed in this section.

Comment: Your expected output is not possible to create. Before you want something, you should validate it first. The format you want is still a lot of errors. Validate your output here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: update json any solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to modify your query, but instead use a collection, which will transform the data after the `get()` method.

```
$PlanDetail = PalnCategory::select('id','title')
    ->with('Categorys','PlanDetails')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('categorys.0.id')
    ->values()
    ->map(function($item){
        $sub = collect($item)->map(function($item){
            $return = collect($item)->forget(['categorys', 'plan_details'])->all();
            $return['plans'] = $item['plan_details'];
            return $return;
        })->toArray();

        $category = $item[0]['categorys'][0];
        $category['categorys'] = $sub;
        return $category;
    });

return response()->json($PlanDetail);
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "category 1",
    "categorys": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "subcategor_name": "regular",
        "plans": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "details": "plan1 reg"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "subcategor_name": "primum",
        "plans": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "details": "plan2 reg2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "category 2",
    "categorys": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "subcategor_name": "cat2 reg",
        "plans": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "details": "plan1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```